# Как предсказать победу одной из трех команд при помощи нейронной сети?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Давно пытаюсь сделать нейронную сеть, которая предскажет победу одной из трех команд.

Итак, представьте, что есть матчи, в которых принимают участие 3 команды, причем выиграть может только одна (ничьих нет).
Нам нужно спрогнозировать победу одной из 3 команд.

Для обучения нейронной сети будут вводиться характеристики каждой команды (например, процент выигрыша команды, какое место в топе и т.д.;какие-то текстовые значения?), а так же номер команды, которая выиграет.

Просмотрев множество сайтов, не нашел такого исполнения нейронной сети.
Обычно просто по данным ввода что-то определяется (например, вводим рост, вес, температуру животного, а нам показывает, что именно это за животное). А у нас должно происходить какое-то сравнение между 3 командами.

Очень прошу помочь и не вводить в ответ сложных терминологий, так как я новичок в этом. Если есть готовые реализации (открытые библиотеки), то было бы хорошо, если бы вы скинули на них ссылку.

Comment: Раньше нейронными сетями занимались? Если нет, советую начать с азов

Comment: У вас есть какие-нибудь мысли по поводу данного вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить простыми словами, то *ИНС* (*И*скусственная *Н*ейронная *С*еть) получает на вход **числовую** матрицу (размерность матрицы может отличаться от задачи, но обычно это от 1 до 4) и возвращает в качестве выхода числовую матрицу (размерность выходной матрицы зависит от задачи, а не от размерности входной матрицы).

Например на вход подается 2D матрица со следующими столбцами:

- рост
- вес
- температура животного
- ...

на выходе мы получаем 1D  матрицу (вектор), указывающий порядковый номер животного или 2D 
 матрицу (каждый столбец которой соответствует одному из определяемых жывотных) с вероятностью того что угадываемое животное принадлежит данному классу.

Так как ИНС работают с числами, им (ИНС) совершенно все равно что стоит за данными числами - животные с их характеристиками или выигрыши конкретной команды с числовыми характеристиками команд.

Поэтому разобравшись с примерами классификации животных, вы легко сможете применить эти знания для вашей задачи.

PS если вас интересует вопрос как преобразовать нечисловые признаки/характеристики в числовые, то об этом стоит задать отдельный SO вопрос с небольшими примерами входных и выходных данных.